# R - assign non-empty cell with respective column name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like:

| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | x | y |
| a | NA | d | b |
| NA | b | y | NA |
| c | x | NA | a |

I would like to replace all non-NA cells (i.e. that have value: a, b, c, d, x, y, z) with the header names:

| header1 | header2 | header3 | header4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | NA | header3 | header4 |
| header1 | NA | header3 | header4 |
| NA | header2 | header3 | NA |
| header1 | header2 | NA | header4 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using `cur_column()` inside `ifelse` and `across`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  header1 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4),
  header2 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4),
  header3 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4),
  header4 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4))

> df
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  header1 header2 header3 header4
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 b       a       NA      b      
2 NA      NA      c       a      
3 a       c       a       c      
4 c       b       b       NA   

> df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~ ifelse(!is.na(.), cur_column(), NA)))
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  header1 header2 header3 header4
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 header1 header2 NA      header4
2 NA      NA      header3 header4
3 header1 header2 header3 header4
4 header1 header2 header3 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Ricardo Semião e Castro's answer works perfectly well using `tidyverse` package and syntax, but you can use base R as well by `for`-looping over the columns:

```
df = data.frame(
  header1 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4),
  header2 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4),
  header3 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4),
  header4 = sample(c(NA, "a", "b", "c"), 4))

colnames <- colnames(df)
for(col in colnames){
  df[[col]][!is.na(df[[col]])] <- col
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it in one assignment in base R without a loop:

```
df[!is.na(df)] <- names(df)[col(df)[!is.na(df)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option (though more verbose than Ricardo's) is to pivot to long format, then use an `ifelse` statement to update the string, then pivot back to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(!is.na(value), name, value),
         row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value") %>% 
  select(-row)
```

**Output**

```
  header1 header2 header3 header4
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 NA      NA      header3 header4
2 header1 NA      header3 header4
3 NA      header2 header3 NA     
4 header1 header2 NA      header4
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(header1 = c(NA, "a", NA, "c"), header2 = c(NA, 
NA, "b", "x"), header3 = c("x", "d", "y", NA), header4 = c("y", 
"b", NA, "a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```